# Changing a model when a set is changed

Tags: python, django

I have a model, let's call it `Post`. I have another model, let's call it `Comment`. A comment can have many posts. In other words, it looks kinda like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):

      post = models.ForeignKey('app.Post', blank=True, null=True)
```

My Post model has a last_modified field, which looks like this

```
class Post(models.Model):

    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When I make changes to `Post` directly, the last modified timestamp easily gets updated. However, I need last_modified to also reflect when the model's comment_set has changed -- in other words, when a `Comment` has been added.

I would like to keep this logic contained in the `Post` model itself instead of having to add it to a Comment's save method or something like that, just so I can keep the models as clean as possible. Is there anything that would function similar to Django's `m2m_changed` model that would allow me to update last_modified when a `Post`'s comment set has changed?

Comment: According to your models, A `post` can have many `comments`. Not otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Django signals like the other answer said. Here you have an example of how to do what you want.

The handler function can be implemented like this:

```
from django.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch importm receiver

import datetime

class Post(models.Model):
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
      post = models.ForeignKey('app.Post', blank=True, null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Comment)
def update_post(request, **kwargs):
    comment = kwargs['instance'] # Instance that receives the signal.
    created = kwargs['created']  # True if was created.
    if created:
        post = comment.post.last_modified = datetime.datetime.now() # Update post date.
        post.save() # Save the modified post.
```

Note: this code has not been tested.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you should investigate using [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).  Specifically, models can send a `post_save` signal indicating when the saving of a model is complete.  In your case, you should probably write a function which receives the signal that a `Comment` has been saved.

Inside of the body of that function, you would update the `last_modified` of the associated `Post`.  In this way, you're basically defining a python trigger to be run on database updates.

Comment: Right idea, but the signal should attach to Comment, to modify the Post whenever a comment has been created.